# hair particles does not move while rigging a character

Tags: mesh, rigging, particles

so i have been doing this character and I put hair particles on it and I Tried to rig it but while rigging it the hair particles Does not move with the hands it stay at the same position , did i miss something here? thanks in advance[image]

Comment: In modifiers make sure that armature is before hair particle system.

Comment: Black Cloud is right. The order of modifiers (hair particles and armatures are modifiers as well) is important here. I had the exact same problem before and it was solved by changing the modifier order.

Comment: yup that worked thank you guys , helpful always